# Allow GCloud service account to access specific user's G Suite account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, service-accounts

We have a use case where we need to allow a service account to access  a *specific* user's G Suite account, but not any other user's. Our first approach was domain-wide delegation, but this is of course far too broad - it gave carte-blanche access to *all* user accounts just by changing the impersonation target, which from a security perspective is not acceptable. And, because this is a server-to-server operation without any UI on top of it, the manual authorization flow is Right Out™ - this has to be achievable either entirely from the G Suite admin panel/GCloud, or by logging in as the user somewhere in the main G Suite.

Is there any way to achieve this? The desired end result is that the service account is able to impersonate *one* user, but attempting to do so with any other yields a permissions violation.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a service account as an identity. So you have an email on this identity.

So you have 2 manner to access to the target user:

- Of course, you can grant access to the whole users with domain wide delegation, and it's too dangerous
- Or, the target user can add the service account email as owner of different things (calendar, documents, drive,...)

*You can also perform this permission grant with another service account with domain wide delegation.*

---

If summary, no mysteries:

- either you are super admin
- or you are authorized by the user to perform action on they behalf